# How to extend length of time for http response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpresponse

Read this but didnt see how to actually extend the time limit for a response:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

```
 string responseContents = string.Empty;

 //get web request to wait 5 mins

 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

 byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
 request.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;

 using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
     requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
     requestStream.Close();
 }

 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 {
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default))
     {
         responseContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
     }
 }
```

Problem being, a lot of stuff going on in the server and takes time to return a response, depending on file size.

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` should to the trick:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds;
```

(...)

Comment: this is saying cant convert double to it?

Comment: I fixed the answer. You need to convert (`(int)`) the total milliseconds from double to int.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in web.config as well

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

Edit: If you want to set it only for a specific controller -

```
<location path="ControllerName/ActionName">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```